# What is wrong with this form validation?

Tags: javascript

Basically, what I am trying to do is alert the same message if one of the seven text boxes in my form is empty. I have been playing around with it a lot, but now I am starting to feel exasperated; help! Sometimes I get a function validepiste() is not defined error and sometimes I don't get an error, but there is an alert even if all the boxes have something in them. I think the error might be due to an incorrect use of the || (or) operator, or the length bit. Here is the function (which is within the head tags):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validatepiste()
{
// all form fields must be filled in
var a= document.piste.nom.length;
var b= document.piste.email.length;
var c= document.piste.numtel.length;
var d= document.piste.adresse.length;
var e= document.piste.ville.length;
var f= document.piste.length;
var g= document.piste.travaux.length;
if (a||b||c||d||e||f||g==0){
  alert("Vous devez remplir toutes les cases.");
  return false;
  }
return true
} 
</script>
```

And the call to that function which is in the html:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Envoyer" onClick="return validatepiste()"/>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code that I can see.

### First Problem

It appears you're trying to access a `length` property directly on a form element (which doesn't exist). What you really want to do is access the `length` of a form value. So instead of this:

```
var a= document.piste.nom.length;
```

Do this:

```
var a= document.piste.nom.value.length;
```

I didn't see this at first but @Napster mentioned it in his answer. So thank him.

### Second Problem

You're if statement has some bad logic. Try the following instead.

```
if (a==0||b==0||c==0||d==0||e==0||f==0||g==0) { ... }
```

Your original expression was asking the following...

If `a` is truthy,
or `b` is truthy,
or `c` is truthy,
or `d` is truthy,
or `e` is truthy,
or `f` is truthy,
or `g` is equal to `0`
then show the alert.

The only scenario which would not have triggered the alert using your existing code would be if all the fields were blank except for `g`.

You can read an [article about what **truthy** means](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2009/07/01/javascript-truthy-falsy/) if you like.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped. Good article too.

Answer (score 1):

You should test each variable's value independently, i.e.:

```
if (a==0||b==0||c==0||e==0||f==0||g==0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. Only you have to add a single thing between where the variable is defined.

Your code:

```
var a= document.piste.nom.length;
var b= document.piste.email.length;
var c= document.piste.numtel.length;
```

Modify it by

```
var a= document.piste.nom.value.length;
var b= document.piste.email.value.length;
var c= document.piste.numtel.value.length;
```

same for all the variable, add value in between them. And your code will run.

Comment: +1 for catching what no one else has caught so far. This is part of the answer. The other part is the broken expression with all the `||`s

Answer (score 0):

First you are not using your || operator correctly. it is only doing comparison of g==0. You are getting always a message because browser takes if(a) as a has some value. So do comparison differently for each varriable like this

```
if (a==0||b==0||c==0||d==0||e==0||f==0||g==0){
```

and second use else condition to return true. It always return true because it is not having else condition. return true always executes. and put semicolon after

```
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its enough if u give

```
onsubmit="validatepiste()"
```

return is not required.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly try:

```
if (a||b||c||d||e||f||g==0){
  alert("Vous devez remplir toutes les cases.");
  return false;
  }
else{
  return true;
}
```

secondly try

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" 
value="Envoyer" onclick="validatepiste()"/>
```

Thirdly:

```
var a= document.getElementByID('nom').length;
```

assuming your form fields have IDs as well as names

Comment: input type submit is having onsubmit event?